# Why am I not able to call a method from a catch block?

Tags: c#, exception

I am trying to call a method which returns an error page from a catch block but it simply would not call the method.

```
try
{
  pt1 = arr[1]; 
  pt2 = arr[2];
}
catch (IndexOutOfRangeException e)
{
  ce.StackTrace =  e.StackTrace;
  Error();
}
```

Here `ce` is a reference to a model which holds properties related to exceptions while `Error()` is an `IActionResult` type function which returns an error page (.cshtml).

Comment: How do you determine if the method was called? Did you put a breakpoint and watched if it got hit?

Comment: Are you sure it even goes into the `catch`?

Comment: Are you sure 'ce' is not null? If the line before "Error()" throws an exception, it will never reach that function.

Comment: If `Error()` yields an `IActionResult`, shouldn't you return that to the client? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Have you used the step debugger?, you are likely just throwing another error, or you are confused about whats happening

Comment: Either your exception is not an `IndexOutOfRangeExcpetion` (or a derivative) or `ce.StackTrace = ...` throws too.

Comment: yes, I made sure that it would get the index out of bounds exceptions. I can see it going into the catch block by using breakpoint, but it simply ignores it and moves forward to the next line.

Comment: maybe you have an excpetion on the previous line (maybe **ce** is null)

Comment: Stop guessing, debug this please

Comment: **Never** catch an `IndexOutOfRangeException`. Instead **avoid** it by checking for the lower and upper bounds **before**.

Comment: Did you re-build your project? Seems your pdb-files are out of date.

Comment: I changed IndexOutOfRangeException with Exception. As I mentioned, I can see it stepping on the function call for Error() inside catch block, but it does not go to the function and return view.

Comment: ce is not null. I get stacktrace inside my ce.stacktrace variable.

Comment: Did you add a breakpoint into `Error` as well to varify this?

Comment: Can you show us what the contents of the `Error()` function are? Also are you debugging a Debug or Release build? If you want your method to return a view you probably want to put the keyword `return` before the `Error()` call.

Comment: public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View();
        }

Comment: this is all I have in the Error method. I mistakenly did all this in release build. Now when I switched to debug mode, it does give a call to the function but does not return the view.

Comment: I have the error view in shared folder while the error method is in Home Controller. does that make any difference?

Comment: It seems like you want to return the result of `Error()` in your catch block instead of just calling it (at the moment it'll call `Error()` but ignore it's result. Have you tried if `return Error();` will give the desired result?

Comment: Sadly that doesn't work. You have a method that returns something of type `A`, which is what you want. Unless there's an exception, then suddenly it should return something of type `B`, but you're not allowed since the method expects something of type `A` to be returned. As far as I know this is exactly why `IActionResult` and `IActionResult<T>` were created, to give the possibilty to return something different depending on certain conditions (like an error).

Comment: If you're looking for a different solution instead of just using `IActionResult` I would advise you to include all relevant code in the question (the method that calls this, including it's return type and the code of `Error()`) that way we can at least see what is exactly going on. Edit: both comments where a response to a now deleted comment where OP claimed that he couldn't use `return Error()` since the method that called this returned something specific as normal flow.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are just lucky and you have three elements in your array.

Also, you may get other kind of exception, which you wouldn't catch, as you are catching only `IndexOutOfrangeException`.

To make sure this exception is thrown, try accessing element at `-1`, i.e. `arr[-1]`.

Also, as alreay mentiond, try setting breakpoint inside `catch` to see, if code there gets executed.